# How to bind data from multiple models to a list in a single view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am new to Mvc and I haven't been able to find any helpful examples. I have a couple of models that I wrap into a Viewmodel. My goal iterate through each item and display the data in a table and later add CRUD functionality.

Here's an example of where I am and what I would like to do in Mvc.

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }  
}

public class Course
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Course { get; set; }
    public string ClassRoom { get; set; }     
}

public class Course_Student
{
    public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller's action method:

```
Course_Student course_Student = new Course_Student();
course_Student.Courses = db.Courses; 
course_Student.Students = db.Students;
return View(course_Student);
```

What I would like on to display in the view:

```
FirstName   LastName   Course    Room
Person      One        Math      C-110
Person      Two        Eng       D-123
Person      Three      Java      B-203
Person      Four       Speech    C-315
```

Comment: You need a relationship between `Student` and `Course`

Comment: You do not NEED a relationship between Student and Course, you can have your database be very simple, a good design pattern is not having relationships in your database, all your relations are business rules and live in the App layer of your software is a way of designing software

Comment: @BrianOgden, OP has 2 tables, 1 for Students and 1 for Courses. If there if no relation between them (a foreign key to indicate which courses belong to which student or vice versa) how do you expect to create the desired view?

Comment: Just as a I demonstrated in my answer. It is a design pattern to not use foreign keys in the database as they are business rules defining relations between data entities. All business rules can live in one layer, normally called an App Layer. The App Layer in this case  is the MVC website and the controllers directly manages relations, it gets the Courses and the Students with two separate simple calls to the database and joins the two datasets as needed with Linq and then populates the ViewModel

Comment: @BrianOgden, But your own answer is creating a `Student` that has a property `CourseIDs` which means there **is** a relationship between `Student` and `Course`.

Comment: Right, and that relationship has to exist as you are pointing out. The knowledge of the relationship between Course and Student must exist somewhere but the database does not have to have any knowledge of this relationship. It exists in the "app layer" and the database does not know of this relationship. Picture all database retrievals as getting collections/rows from the database. And then the app layer combines and filters these "raw" collections based on relationships aka business rules using Linq. In my suggested answer the ViewModel house the combined Course and Student

Comment: And the knowledge that a Course and Student have any relation is only in the Controller. I have a Domain Driven Design project that I have been working on the last 6 months that does it like this, its a pain in the ass at first but I am noticing how powerful it is with repetition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a collection of Courses in the Student class so that all Courses are link to from the Student class (or vice versa if you like).

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int[] CourseIDs { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public string ClassRoom { get; set; }
}
```

Your view model should then be simplified and data should be joined together to make it easier in the View.

```
public class CourseStudent
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Course { get; set; }
    public string Room { get; set; }
}

public class CourseStudentViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<CourseStudent> CourseStudents { get; set; }
}
```

Then you should be able to get it to work if your Controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var courses = new Collection<Course>
    {
        new Course {CourseId = 1, ClassRoom = "C-110", CourseName = "Math"},
        new Course {CourseId = 2, ClassRoom = "D-123", CourseName = "Eng"},
        new Course {CourseId = 3, ClassRoom = "B-203", CourseName = "Java"},
        new Course {CourseId = 4, ClassRoom = "C-315", CourseName = "Speech"},
    };

    var students = new Collection<Student>
    {
        new Student{StudentId = 1, FirstName = "Person", LastName = "One", CourseIDs = new []{1}},
        new Student{StudentId = 2, FirstName = "Person", LastName = "Two", CourseIDs = new []{2}},
        new Student{StudentId = 3, FirstName = "Person", LastName = "Three", CourseIDs = new []{3}},
        new Student{StudentId = 4, FirstName = "Person", LastName = "Four", CourseIDs = new []{4}},
    };

    var courseStudents = from student in students
        from course in courses
        where student.CourseIDs.Any(x => x.Equals(course.CourseId))
        select new CourseStudent
        {
            FirstName = student.FirstName,
            LastName = student.LastName,
            Course = course.CourseName,
            Room = course.ClassRoom
        };
    var courseStudentViewModel = new CourseStudentViewModel{CourseStudents = courseStudents};

    return View(courseStudentViewModel);
}
```

And a View like this:

```
@model MvcApplication1.CourseStudentViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<table>
    <tbody><tr><th>FirstName</th><th>LastName</th><th>Course</th><th>Room</th></tr></tbody>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var row in Model.CourseStudents)
        {
            <tr><td>@row.FirstName</td><td>@row.LastName</td><td>@row.Course</td><td>@row.Room</td></tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And then the results as a html table:

[image: Results as a html table]

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue, is that your ViewModel is a bit off.

```
public class CourseViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Course_Student> PageData{ get; set; }
}

public class Course_Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; } 
    public string Course { get; set; }
    public string ClassRoom { get; set; }        
}
```

With your ViewModel fixed, now your view is clear

```
@model CourseViewModel


<table>
 <th>FirstName</th>
 <th>LastName</th>
 ...etc
 @foreach(var cs in model.PageData){
  <tr><td>@cs.FirstName</td><td>@cs.LastName</td>...etc</tr>
 }
</table>
```

With this, you should be able to see now how to populate your ViewModel in your controller action method. You can use Linq very easily to do this. Or you can do a for loop for Courses and create a result Course_Student for each Course and build you your List for CoureViewModel.PageData, let me know if you need help with that part.